# Ehcache - How does ehcache get to know about the current memory size

Tags: ehcache

I donot see anywhere in Put function of Cache , that the sizeof Object or anything similar to it is being called . So how does ehCache comes to know the current memory filled. 
I know there are other function to get that , but they need to be called explicitly.
I want to know at the runtime , how does it know the memoey filled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, Ehcache will only size objects on heap if it is configured to do so. And when it is, the sizing happens inside the on-heap store and ARC related code not in the `Cache.put` method.

So if you want to track down the code, start from `net.sf.ehcache.store.MemoryStore#put` and see also `net.sf.ehcache.pool.impl.AbstractPoolAccessor#add(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, boolean)`.

Comment: I didnt get it completely.

Comment: 1 . if u want to put memory boundation like maximum bytes on heap . You have to have the measure in bytes of objects ??

Comment: if you size your cache's heap store in bytes (maxBytesLocalHeap), indeed each new put's data Element will be sized in Bytes by the sizeOf library...which I understand is what Louis says (he's just saying that this sizeOf call is not done directly in the put() method...rather in the AbstractPoolAccessor#add). Hopes that makes sense.

Comment: ok .. so internally put calls AbstractPoolAccessor#add which calls size of